# Retrieving port number in-application using Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework

I have two Play framework web applications running on my system on ports 9001 and 9002. I was wondering if there was any way I could retrieve which port they were running on from within my Java code.

Is this possible?

Comment: You should at least point which version of Play are you using, I assume that getting working port on version 1 and 2 will be different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can get the port like this:

```
int port = Integer.parseInt(Play.configuration.getProperty("http.port", 9000));
```

Of course, you have to import the class `play.Play`.

Answer (score 2):

In Play 2.4.x:

```
Play.application().configuration().getString("http.port");
```

or simply:

```
System.getProperty("http.port");
```

This only works in production mode, when the http.port is set via the Java -D parameter.

Answer (score 1):

*Since the system does not let me comment yet, I'm forced to add my comment here.*

The given answer by Carsten must be for play1, for play2 see [Retrieving port number in Play Framework 2 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970677/retrieving-port-number-in-play-framework-2-app)