# Play Framework: How to get the current port number

Tags: scala, playframework

How do I get the current port number in a Play application? I use scala.

Comment: You tried this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970677/retrieving-port-number-in-play-framework-2-app

Comment: What is version of Playframework you use?

Comment: I'm using Play 2.3.8

Comment: Yes... I've seen the post mentioned by Identity1... but it doesn't help. I'm looking for a more robust solution.

Comment: ..What is more robust than pulling the port from the app configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here below is my solution:

```
def localHost()(implicit request: RequestHeader = null): Host = {
  def loadFromConfig = {
    val ssl = config.getBoolean("ssl").getOrElse(false)
    val host = config.getString("host").getOrElse(EndPoint.DefaultHostName)
    val port = Play.isTest match {
      case false => System.getProperty("http.port", null) match {
          case port if port != null => parse[Int](port).getOrElse(EndPoint.DefaultPort)
          case _ => EndPoint.DefaultPort
        }
      case _ => System.getProperty("testserver.port", null) match {
          case port if port != null => parse[Int](port).getOrElse(EndPoint.DefaultTestPort)
          case _ => EndPoint.DefaultTestPort
        }
    }
    Host(EndPoint(host, port), ssl)
  }

  request match {
    case null => if (_localHost == null) this.synchronized {
        if (_localHost == null) _localHost = loadFromConfig
      }
      _localHost
    case _ => Host(EndPoint(Some(request.host)), request.secure)
  }
}
```

I hope it helps.